# 404 Error with Angularjs TemplateUrl Routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

I am following [this tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating), trying to have a SPA inside my MVC3 application where the SPA is called by a controller, DemoController.cs.

I am getting 404 errors when the app tries to load the different Templates, (about.html, contact.html, and home.html) via a nav bar.

This is my directory structure (not including the rest of the MVC3 app):

```
Scripts
-script.js 
Views
-Demo
--pages
---about.html
---contact.html
---home.html
--Index.cshtml
--_ViewStart.cshtml
```

This is my script.js file where i define the routes.

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', []);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

This is my index.html code:

```
    <div ng-app="scotchApp">
    <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div id="main">
            <!-- angular templating -->
            <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With help from the Google Group for AngularJS, which I highly recommend to everyone who needs angularjs help, I now know what went wrong and how to better troubleshoot these kinds of issues.

Here is the tips that I recieved from one of its members:

> I can’t say what the issue is specifically in your situation, but in
> general the way you would troubleshoot it is to check the following:
>
> Is the server configured to return the templates as static html?
> Verify this by constructing a url manually and loading it directly
> with a browser (not involving angular at all). You should be able to
> see the static html. This is a pre-requisite for anything else
> working. If this doesn't work then the problem is properly configuring
> .NET and server-side routing.
>
> If the you can get the first step to
> work, then start your angular app and open up the network tab of your
> browser’s development tool. If you see 404 requests note the URL. How
> is it different than the working URL you used above?
>
> If the URL is
> different, modify the templateUrl parameter accordingly so that it
> matches the correct URL. If you are still having issues, post an
> example of the working URL and an example of what URL the browser is
> requesting when it gets a 404.

Combine this with the fact that I wasn't able to pull up the templates with a static url I found another SO question that directly fixed this issue.  [How do you request static .html files under the ~/Views folder in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/request-static-html-files-in-asp-net-mvc)

**Answer to my question:**
So I created a ~/Static folder to house all of my templates and now my angular app works perfectly because when i request a tempate i can give it a direct url to get it from.

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can fix in 2 ways:

method 1: add hash sign like this: `<a href="#/about">`

method 2: or use html5Mode by setting `[$locationProvider][1].html5Mode(true);`

like this:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {...
```

Comment: I have the $locationProvider html5mode set to true, yet still seeing the error page

Answer (score 0):

For future followers, you need to serve all views from public directory, where you set in `express.static`. 
Or, you can use require() with transform `html2js-browserify` in browserify, or `raw` loader in webpack, I know post is out of date:)