# Why doesnt my $routeProvider work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

I am having trouble getting my $routeProvider to work correctly.

I have the following code:

```
"use strict";

(function() {
    angular.module("websiteApp", ["ngRoute"])

        .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when("/example", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/example.html",
                    controller: "ExampleController"
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: "/"
                });
        }]);
})();
```

but when I navigate to `localhost/example` I get `404 Not Found`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the real ExampleController belonging to the app, or is it just a dummy value?

Comment: Also have a look at this article, maybe you experience similar issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307655/404-error-with-angularjs-templateurl-routing

Comment: @mhmtztmr I have a real `ExampleController`

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply you are using the wrong url. Unless you set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` all the angular paths will be hash based and include `#` in them

Try

```
http://localhost#/example
```

So you also need to include the hash in any `href` you use also

```
<a href="#/example">
```

Note that `html5Mode` also requires server configuration if you decide to implement it

Comment: Where do I declare this? In the config?

Comment: yes but only if you are prepared to configure server also