# Angularjs Routing error

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am developing asp.net mvc project with angularjs routing. Indroducing some routing errors while reloading page. In my application,

```
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/Home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
```

This page works fine if I reload page. But, If I reload the next page it shows Server Error in '/' Application. HTTP: 404 error.

```
.when('/computer', {
        templateUrl: '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/Laptop.html',
        controller: 'LaptopController'
    })
```

I appreciate for the answer.

Comment: probably that old answer can help you "[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307655/404-error-with-angularjs-templateurl-routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307655/404-error-with-angularjs-templateurl-routing)"

Comment: html5Mode is true?

Comment: if you are using Html5Mode your server needs to be configured as well as angular.  What server technology are you using?  The folks that wrote UI-Router also wrote a very good FAQ that talks about this and gives configuration options for many popular servers: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: I am using IIS...I'll try  UI-Router also..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help "stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request-with-angularjs-html5-mode"

Comment: Edited answer. If you have html5mode enabled that question should help you.

Comment: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); Doesn't work

Comment: Remove that .hashPrefix() and on the server side create a .htaccess file inside your root folder and paste this:                                
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

Comment: I have created a .htaccess file where web.config/setup file located...But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I just saw you are using ISS , what I told your is for Apache. Claies commented on your answer with a link to how to do this for ISS. Try that.