# Using asp.net partial views in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use static html partial viewd from the asp.net mvc views folder in angularjs, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible at all or I must create a new folder for these? Ideally I would like to keep all views in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the static files in Views folder by changing web.config setting to this.

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

You need to change `path="*"` to `path="*.cshtml"`, this will allow all other file types to be allowed directly.

I answered this question in bit more detail here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789089/3421839