# I can't get templateUrl to work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm new to Angular and I'm using Angular-UI-Router with ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('about', {
        url: '/',
        template: 'HELLO WORLD'
    });
}]);
```

this works fine.  HELLO WORLD is displaying so i know that everything is set up rather correctly.

but when i try templateUrl instead of template say:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');  //if you go to incorrect url it'll go back to home

$stateProvider
    .state('about', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'Home/About.html'
    });
}]);
```

nothing displays.  I'm using almost a clean slate default template from scratch.. picking the "Internet Application" from default templates.. in my directories i have

Views --> Home --> About.html

I also have About.cshtml and I've tried that and it doesn't work neither. Help please!

Comment: Try using `/home/about.html` - notice the slash at the beginning.

Comment: did you enable `html` file access inside your mvc project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: i'll try all of these and get back to you guys.  Thank you for the replies

Comment: @callmekatootie didn't work unfortunately.. i tried all the combos i could think of

Comment: @PankajParkar i made a static folder under the main project and made an about.html and pointed it there as '/static/about.html' and 'static/about.html' and still no dice.  so frustrated

Comment: @PankajParkar actually wait it worked!  you can put the answer and i'll give you credit

Comment: Check your browser's developer console - check also the network tab and try to determine which route or path the browser is attempting to get the templateUrl

Comment: @user1189352 look at the answer which I've added

Comment: @callmekatootie thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC `Views` doesn't allow direct access to `.html` files of it. You need to allow the access from the `web.config` by adding handlers in `system.webServer`

**Code**

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="JavaScriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />      
  <add name="HtmlScriptHandler" path="*.html" verb="*"
     preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Or the other way around would be you could create one new static folder other than `Views` that will have an `html` files in it. You could directly access the `URL` eg. `static/about.html`

For more details refer [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc)