# How to mention angular custom directive templateUrl path when working with Asp.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i have a sample directive where i need to mention templateUrl file location. my template file exist in this location `Views/Home/searchableMultiselect.html`

```
app.directive("showdata", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl: '~/Views/Home/searchableMultiselect.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
```

the above code is in app.js file. now tell me how to instruct angular to load template file from this location '~/Views/Home/searchableMultiselect.html'

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body data-root='@Url.Content("~")'>
```

In Javascript:

```
function getDataRoot() {
    var root = null;

    if (document.body) {
        root = document.body.getAttribute('data-root');
    }

    if (!root) {
        return '/';
    }

    return root;
}

// This can be registed with angular, so it can be injected...
// Right now I will use it directly
var appUrls = {
    templateBase = getDataRoot() + 'Views/Home/';
}

....

app.directive("showdata", function ($timeout) {
return {
    templateUrl: appUrls.templateBase + 'searchableMultiselect.html',
    restrict: 'AE',
```

Comment: no did not work i got this error `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:2283/Views/Home/searchableMultiselect.html"`

Comment: You are supposed to adapt it to fit your case. It is unlikely it would work out of the box. The idea is there though...

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an asp.net mvc app, you should take advantage of helper methods like `Url.Action` or `Url.Content` or `Url.RouteUrl`. In your razor view you may use either of these methods to generate the path to your app base root/or a specific root and pass that to your angular controller/angular services/directives.

So in your razor view/layout file, you may do this.

```
@section Scripts
{
   <script src="~/Scripts/YourAngularControllerFileForThisPage.js"></script>
   <script>
        var yourApp = yourApp || {};
        yourApp.Settings = yourApp.Settings || {};
        yourApp.Settings.BaseUrl= "@Url.Content("~")";
        angular.module("app").value("appSettings", yourApp);
   </script>
}
```

You can access this `appSettings` object in your angular directive and use the `Settings.BaseUrl` property to build the full url to your directive template.

```
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
        .directive("myDirective", function (appSettings) {           
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: appSettings.Settings.BaseUrl
                                       +'Scripts/MyDirectives/searchableMultiselect.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    // some code
                }
            }
        });
})();
```

This will load the `searchableMultiselect.html` file from `~/Scripts/MyDirectives` location.

Comment: no luck...did not work i got this error "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:2283/Views/Home/searchableMultiselect.html"

Comment: No. [That is by design](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17949486/40521). You are not supposed to directly access contents inside your Views folder. Since it is an angular directive, I suggest putting under the Scripts folder ( you may create a sub directory there)

Comment: i am getting this error.....what i am missing. i am new in angular. the error `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/nomod?p0=app
 

return new ErrorConstructor(message);`

Comment: i declare my module in app.js this way `var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.bootstrap"]);`

Comment: May be the order of loading ? Are you sure you have all the files needed in the right order ? The above code should work fine. I just verified in a local project.

Comment: i am new in ng so may made mistake for order of loading. can u please give me a jsfiddle version so i can see the order. thanks

Comment: yes problem solved. there was problem of loading order and fixed now. thanks a lot :)