# View not loading in Asp.net angular app. Angular Routing with Asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I'm trying to route a simple view in ASP.NET AngularJs app but the view not loading on the browser ngView is commented out in browser.

## JavaScript

```
(function () {

"use strict";

angular.module("app-trips", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            $controller: "tripsController",
            $controllerAs: "vm",
            $templateUrl: "/views/tripsView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/editor", {
            $controller: "tripEditorController",
            $controllerAs: "vm",
            $templateUrl: "/views/tripEditorView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : "/"});
    });

})();
```

## CHTML

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.Trip>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home"; 
}

@section Scripts{ 
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/simpleControls.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app-trips.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/tripsController.js"></script>
}

<div ng-app="app-trips">
    <div ng-view></div>
</
```

## Results

[image: Browser inspection]

[image: URL Bar]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` sign from your `$routeProvider` route properties.

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    controller: "tripsController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    templateUrl: "/views/tripsView.html"
});
```

> **Note:** If you're using .NET MVC project, [you can't access html files directly from `views`
>   folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949486/2435473). I'd recommend to create a new folder and put static html files there.

Comment: sorry to say it's not solving my problem. this is ASP.NET Core there is no web.config.

Comment: @RxNReza I guess same rules applies to asp net core, create a new static folder and place all html there.