# Redirect to view from global.asax not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

How to Redirect to view from global.asax?

Below is my code. It gives me HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] == "true")
        {
            //  if (!Request.IsLocal)
            //  {
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Clear();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Account/MaintenancePage.cshtml");
            // }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/MaintenancePage");`

Comment: I tried. But it shows me "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: Try passing false to second parameter like `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/MaintenancePage", false);`. Also, ensure that `/Account/MaintenancePage` is valid url

Comment: Tried. same message " "The page isn’t redirecting properly" :-(

Comment: And you have checked that you can browse to `/Account/MaintenancePage` in the browser?

Comment: It gives me 500.19 when I try to browse

Comment: You need to reveal the 500.19 error page as it contains the necessary info.

Answer (score 2):

Add `MaintenancePage` GET action in your `Account` controller, which looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MaintenancePage()
{
    return View();
}
```

And then point to this `action` this way to prevent infinite redirection loop:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Account/MaintenancePage");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it giving me StackOverflow exceptions

Comment: Check in `Application_BeginRequest` method if you are already from "/Account/MaintenancePage"

Comment: how do i check that?

Comment: I checked. No I am in account/indexpage

Answer (score 1):

In cases of maintenance mode, or error checking, I redirect to a static html page using Server.Transfer.

```
Server.Transfer("/Error.html");
```

I keep Error.html in the root of the project.

Comment: Its a MVC application. So Instead of keeping in root directory I created a view inside views/account folder

Comment: By the way, static page is just a file so for maintenace purposes it makes sense to consider this scenario instead of controller actions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Already have one view folder. I do not want to duplicate the views.